# Is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 with a Pivot 1 a worst-case Quick-Sort Scenario and why?

Tags: pivot, quicksort

The question might be too easy, but I really don't understand why, for example, 1,2,3,4,5 with a Pivot in the beginning is a worst-case scenario.

I am new to it, so could you please explain it to me very simply? What is compared to what and how many times?

Thanks a lot,

Dasha